# Correct usage of R-package "Rblpapi" connecting Bloomberg with R

Tags: r, bloomberg

I'm using the Rblpapi R-package which provides a direct connection between Bloomberg data and R. Unfortunately I'm unable to get the members of the German CDAX at any time except today.

The following function returns the current CDAX members:

```
require(RBLpapi)

bds("CDAX Index","INDX_MWEIGHT_HIST")
```

I tried to obtain the CDAX members at earlier dates using

```
bds("CDAX INDEX","INDX_MWEIGHT_HIST",overrides=c(INDX_DATE="20150831"))
```

but it does not work. Can anybody help me with that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you try to use quotes around INDX_DATE ?

Comment: thanks a lot! It worked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the correct syntax but need to use a different override for INDX_MWEIGHT_HIST to ensure that it gives you the correct data. You can check this by running [this page](http://blinks.bloomberg.com/screens/cdax%20index%20flds%20indx%20mweight%20hist) then clicking into the field details.

The appropriate request would be:

```
bds("cdax index", "indx_mweight_hist", overrides=c(end_date_override="20150831"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really helpful!